# Understanding two-way databinding in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm new to polymer, and I've been reading the docs and playing around with it a little bit, but I'm having some difficulty understanding the difference between the [[]] one way data flow, and the {{}} two way data flow.

Can anyone help me understand the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example handing data from one element down to one of it's child elements is considered one-way-data-binding. If this data get's modified in the child element the change is also reflected in the parent. This is made possible through a two-way-data-binding as it can go in both directions up and down.


Below I have added two code examples.
The first illustrates *one-away-data-binding* between two elements. The second example shows *two-way-data-binding* where the parent element reflects a change that happened in it's child.

Please note that I am using the syntax of Polymer 1. However, I believe the way data-binding is handled in Polymer 2 hasn't changed.

**One-way-data-binding**
*Parent Element*

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../child-element/child-element.html">
<dom-module id="parent-element">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
    <div>
      <h1>[[name]]</h1> <!-- This will print Pazzle -->

      <!-- Use the imported child element and bind the name property-->
      <child-element name="[[name]]"></child-element>
      <!-- Will print Pazzle in a h2 element -->

    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'parent-element',
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: String,
          value: 'Pazzle'
        }
      },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

*Child of parent-element:*

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="child-element">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
    <div>
      <h2>[[name]]</h2> <!-- This will print Pazzle -->
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'child-element',
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: String,
          value: ''
        }

      },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**Two-way-data-binding**
*Parent Element*

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../child-element/child-element.html">
<dom-module id="parent-element">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
    <div>
      <!-- Use the imported child element and bind the name property-->
      <child-element name="{{name}}"></child-element>
      <!-- Will print Contis in a h2 element instead of Pazzle -->

    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'parent-element',
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: String,
          value: ''
        }
      },

      ready: function() {
        this.name = "Pazzle";
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

*Child of parent-element:*

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="child-element">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
    <div>
      <h2>[[name]]</h2> <!-- This will print Contis -->
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'child-element',
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: String,
          value: '',
          notify: true,
          // notify will make it possible to send
          // our changed Name property back up
          observer: 'nameChanged'
        }
      },

      nameChanged: function() {
        if(this.name == 'Pazzle' || this.name == ''){
          this.name = "Contis";
        }
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: In Polymer docs [try Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/quick-tour) section 'Use data binding' it uses curly braces `{{}}`. that is the related [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8mZK8S?p=preview) linked there. Why it does not use square brackets `[[]]`?

Comment: @Işık I don't think there is any point in doing this. This is either a mistake or just for demo purposes. But feel free to prove me wrong. In the example they are binding to a normal html element two way binding would only make sense to the property as shown in the example below the one that you linked

Comment: I mean especially that. the one I have linked is just a string template, it deos not bind to a property, so two way data binding does not make sense it does not hurt but it is effectively a one way binding with square brakets. So it is a mistake maybe as you said. Am I right?

Comment: Yes thats what I am thinking. It doesn't harm as you sad but I would try to avoid it if it is not need as Polymer handles it differently under the hood which will result in unnecessary work