# Get value from other element in Polymer 1

Tags: html, polymer-1.0

I have a "login-imp.html" file (polymer 1 element) that checks the login and gets username and someID.

I need to retrieve that "someID" in other polymer element that is in another html file (modal-imp.html).

**login-imp.html**

```
<dom-module id="login-imp">
<style>...</style>
  <template>

<iron-ajax id="limp" url="SOMEURL" method="POST" handle-as="json"
  content-type="application/json" with-credentials="true" on-response="_handleResponse" on-error="_handleError">
</iron-ajax>

<iron-a11y-keys keys="enter" on-keys-pressed="_logIn"></iron-a11y-keys>

<div class="login">
  <paper-input value={{username}} label="[[lang.login_imp.user]]" name="username"></paper-input>
  <paper-input value="{{password}}" label="[[lang.login_imp.password]]" name="password" type="password"></paper-input>
  <span class="error-message">[[errorMessage]]</span>
  <paper-button id="login-button" on-tap="_logIn" raised>[[lang.login_imp.signin]]</paper-button>
</div>


<paper-dialog id="modalSignUp" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" with-backdrop>
  <modal-signup-imp id="modal-signup-view" lang="[[lang]]" config="[[config]]"></modal-signup-imp>
</paper-dialog>

  </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
          is: 'login-imp',
          properties: {
            loggedIn: {
              type: Boolean,
              notify: true
            },        
            profile: {
              type: Object,
              notify: true,
              value: function () {
                return {}
              }
            },
            username: {
              type: String,
              notify: true,
              value: ''
            },
            password: {
              type: String,
              notify: true,
              value: ''
            },
            retailerId: {
              type: String,
              notify: true,
              value: ''
            },
            config: {
              type: String
            },
            default: {
              type: Array,
              notify: true
            },
            lang: {
              type: String
            },
            errorMessage: String,
            observers: ['_removeMessage(username, password)']
          },
          ready: function () {
            this.addEventListener('eventFromChild', this.closeModal);
          },
          _logIn: function () {
            Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#login-button").disabled = true;

            this.$.limp.body = JSON.stringify({
              "username": this.username,
              "password": this.password
            });
            this.$.limp.generateRequest();
          },
          _handleResponse: function (xhrResponse) {
            Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#login-button").disabled = false;
            var message = xhrResponse.detail.response.message;
            if (message == "Access granted (" + this.username + ")") {
              // save profile
              this.profile = xhrResponse.detail.response.user
              // change status to logged in
              this.loggedIn = true;
              this.username = '';
              this.password = '';
//THIS IS THE ID I NEED
              this.retailerId = xhrResponse.detail.response.user.id_retailer;
              this._removeMessage();
            }
          },
          _handleError: function (event) {
            Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#login-button").disabled = false;

            this.errorMessage = [
              [this.lang.errors.signin]
            ];
            this.loggedIn = false;
          },
          _removeMessage: function () {
            this.set('errorMessage', '');
          },
          signup_modal: function () {
            Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#modal-signup-view").xhrRetailers();

            var modal = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#modalSignUp");
            modal.open();
          },
          closeModal: function () {
            var modal = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#modalSignUp");
            modal.close();
          }
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
```

I've tried every way to access that object from modal-imp.html as indicated in the Polymer 1 API and docs.

-The html *hierarchy*:

login-imp.html -> main-imp.html -> index.html

modal-imp.html -> header-imp.html -> main-imp.html -> index.html

Answer (score 0):

The code inside your login-imp.html file looks fine. You defined the retailerId as a property and have set notify to true. I presume without seeing the other files that you most likely used a wrong binding.

**To clarify in your example:**
What you will have to do is send the retailerId up to main-imp.html
From there you bind it down to header-imp.html and further to modal-imp.html

**Example:**
Inside your main-imp.html

```
<login-imp retailer-id="{{retailerId}}"></login-imp>
```

**Important:**

1. You have to use {{mustaches}} brackets when binding in two ways (in your case up)
2. The attribute had to be written in lower case so your property name changes to retailer-id
3. Define retailerId inside your main-imp.html property section

**Similar Problems**
[Maybe a similar question I have answered explaining one & two way data-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46601145/6213524)

Comment: So, I have to add "retailerid" as property in main, header and modal and `retailer-id:"{{retailerid}}"` inside each element. Something else for the main-to-modal road? Thanks!!!

Comment: This `retailer-id:"{{retailerid}}"` is only for the upwards binding between login-imp & main-imp. For the downwards binding you will have to use `retailer-id:"[[retailerid]]"` in header-imp.html.
Take a look at the answer in the link i have added